# Importing a file in another folder in a parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I know that maybe you have faced this question many times. But since I couldn't find a solution to answer this question, I wanted to write it here again. For example:

```
main/
  model/
    mod1.py
  lib/
    mod2.py
```

I have a folder structure as above.
I want to import the mod2.py file in the lib folder to the mod1.py file in the model folder.  For this, I add the following line to the mod1 file.

```
lib.mod2 as mod2
```

But when I do this I get the following error.

```
No module named 'lib.mod2'
```

Can you help me?

> Python version : 3.10.4

Comment: Run your script from `main` folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have a folder structure like this

```
main/
  model/
    mod1.py
  lib/
    mod2/
    mod2.py
```

First, create a `__init__.py` in the folder from which you want to import the file.
For this structure , it will look like this

```
main/
  model/
    mod1.py
  lib/
    mod2/
    mod2.py
    __init__.py
```

after this, you can type

`from main.lib import mod2`
and it should work correctly